# XSLT Get Current date or Today in XSLT

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

Help please can anyone advise how I get current date, or today method in xslt 1.o SharePoint

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if XSLT 1.0 have today's date method. However, XSLT 2.0 has an equivalent `current-date()`

Have you tried?

**ddwrt:Today()**

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:Today()"/>
```

**ddwrt:TodayIso()**

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:Today(),1033,'yyyyMMdd')"/>
```

Comment: Note that SharePoint still uses the XSLT 1.0 spec (as of SharePoint 2010) so XSLT 2.0 functionality won't help.

Answer (score 8):

When you add a DVWP to the page in SharePoint Designer, SPD defined a variable which contains the current date for you in the ParameterBindings section:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
```

Be sure to declare Today as a param at the top of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:param name="Today" />
```

Then you can use $Today however you need it.

The ddwrt:Today() function is also useful, but there's no real need for it when SPD is already handing you the value.

Comment: Actually, there is. Using `$Today` led to wrong results when comparing dates for conditional formatting. Being in NZ, I saw results change at noon, which is midnight in GMT. Maybe this does not matter for US locales, but for NZ locale I get correct results with `ddwrt:today()` and wrong results with `$Today`.